# can not open design xamarin android visual studio 2017

Tags: xamarin.android

maybe someone know my problem,
i can't open axml file on android project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1II6.png)

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: o
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetIUnknownForObjectNative(Object o, Boolean onlyInContext)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows.WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.UpdateD3DImageFromSharedSurface() in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows\WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.cs:line 140
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows.WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.RenderDesignerItemVisual(DesignerItem item) in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows\WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.cs:line 131
   at Xamarin.Designer.Windows.WpfSurfaceRenderer.QueueRender(DesignerItem item) in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer.Windows\WpfSurfaceRenderer.cs:line 361
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSurface.HandleSessionImageChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSurface.cs:line 229
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSession.OnImageChanged() in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSession.cs:line 2321
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSession.HandleRendered(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSession.cs:line 1381
```

- visual studio 2017 Version 15.5.7
- xamarin 4.8.0.760
- xamarin.android SDK 8.1.5.0

Comment: I'm having this same problem too. It happened right after changing the form factor in the designer. Would love to change it back but I don't see the option to if the designer crashes.

Comment: @Ubarjohade if you create new app, and open the design, it's working or not ?

Comment: Yeah that will work, it is saved in the project settings somewhere.